# Generate webfont with Grunt plugin grunt-webfont on Windows

Tags: windows, svg, fonts, gruntjs, webfonts

With my team work, we have to generate a webfont of icons from svg files for our backoffice.
For doing this with Grunt, we found a plugin named "grunt-webfont".

Here the link : [grunt-webfont repository](https://github.com/sapegin/grunt-webfont)

My problem is that doesn't generate correctly our webfont on Windows. Instead of an icon, i have a little square.

By default, the task starts with the `engine` params `fontforge`, but it's doesn't work on Windows. So i try to set this option with `node` (with ttfautohint dependency). But it doesn't work either.

Here my plugin config :

```
dev: {
  src: '<%= project.app %>/images/pictos/*.svg',
  dest: '<%= project.app %>/styles/fonts/',
  options: {
    font: 'my-icons',
    stylesheet: 'scss',
    syntax: 'bem',
    htmlDemo: true,
    relativeFontPath: 'fonts/my/',
    engine: (grunt.option('engine') || 'fontforge'),
    templateOptions: {
      baseClass: 'my-icon',
      classPrefix: 'my-icon-',
      mixinPrefix: 'my-icon-'
    },
  }
}
```

It seems to be good when i do :

`$ grunt serve --engine="node"`

The result is :

`Running "webfont:dev" (webfont) task
Font my-icons-738111b522f08be9663c9b5af0606fd5 with 24 glyphs created.`

But still little squares...

I tried to set 'autohint' option to 'false', and same result...

My work team do this with Ubuntu and it's work great ! What kind of solution i have to do this on Windows ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done with some svg on Windows.

The [Readme.md](https://github.com/sapegin/grunt-webfont/blob/master/Readme.md) of Grunt-webfont says that their product won't work with Fontforge on Windows. So your only option is Node.

Also, in the [Readme.md](https://github.com/sapegin/grunt-webfont/blob/master/Readme.md): Node doesn’t work with some SVG files. So check with the Ubuntu team if they can render your svg file with Node and not get squares.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
We have check our SVG files and the problem seems to be the same on Linux with 'node' engine. Do you have recommandations about SVG files for the conversion ?
I will post an issue on the Github repository too.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems using Grunt Webfont in Windows using the Node engine. Most shapes worked, but a large amount containing shapes within shapes just gave a outline of the icon.

During my own search for a solution I found this article describing how to achieve this using a Vagrant to build the fonts from windows: 
http://mac-blog.org.ua/grunt-webfont-windows/

Fontello (both web site and Grunt plugin) has similar problems. For my svg icons the problem seemed to be related to fill rules, e.g. even-odd. They have good documentation explaining more on this matter: https://github.com/fontello/fontello/wiki/How-to-use-custom-images#importing-svg-images

Regarding my own journey, I ended up using icomoon.io which supported these more advanced svg features.

Answer (score 0):

You mean little squares like `[]`, or a tiny dots representing your icons (and looking similar to them in font-size is increased)?

If tiny dots, that may be a problem of too small source SVG files. Resize them to 512px height (both canvas and inner content), regenerate font, and you'll have you icons.

P.S. I also use grunt-webfont on Windows, both engines (node/fontforge) work somehow for me.

Comment: And if little squares like `[]`, please provide some link to your SVG, maybe I'll find out whats is the problem with these "some SVG files on Windows"